# Collapsing Columns in different orders in foundation

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, multiple-columns

Not sure if this is possible but i'm wanting to code the following columns in Foundation 5 to collapse like the below.

**Large:**
[1][2][3][4]

**Medium:**
[1][4]
[2][3]

**Small:**
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]

Medium is the breakpoint that is screwing me over.

Can someone help?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenging one. I think you have a few options that both use nesting. One would get you the correct layout on `medium` but won't work on `small`..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">1</div>
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 large-push-6 columns">4</div>
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 large-pull-6 columns">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The other option is to duplicate the last row and use the visibility classes..

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">1</div>
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 columns">2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 columns">
        <div class="row show-for-medium-up">
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 large-push-6 columns">4</div>
            <div class="large-6 medium-12 large-pull-6 columns">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row show-for-small-only">
            <div class="small-12 large-push-6 columns">3</div>
            <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-pull-6 columns">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/pZqRjFqwX9

Answer (score 0):

Hi "Source Ordering" would push your columns outside the grid, but you could show/hide other columns.

See: [Foundation 5 Grid Push Pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723271/foundation-5-grid-push-pull)

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6p6uguL/3/

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns show-for-medium"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-4 columns hide-for-medium"><h1>4</h1></div>
</div>
```